# Readjust four column values by ignoring blank cells (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this values:

[image]

And I would like the formula to **ignore blank cells**, with the final result in the following sequence:

[image]

I tried to use the `QUERY + TRANSPOSE`, but I couldn't adjust it as I need it, I failed to try to include `IF` to remove the blank cells with `IF(A1:D=""` and continue `QUERY`, but it also failed.

Failed test:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(trim(split(transpose(query(transpose(A1:D),,999^99))," ",true,true)), "where Col1 <> '' "))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modified formula?

#### Modified formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:D),"(([\w\s]+,){3}[\w\s]+)","$1@"),"@")),",")))
```

- The flow of this formula is as follows.

  1. Join all cell values by ignoring the empty cells using `TEXTJOIN`.
  2. Put `@` to the joined text value for 4 columns using `REGEXREPLACE`.
  3. Split the text value with `@` using `SPLIT`.
  4. Transpose the splitted values using `TRANSPOSE`.
  5. Split the each row with `,` using `SPLIT`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- If `,` and `@` are included in the cell values, please change them in the formula.

#### References:

- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)
- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)

### Added 1:

About `I guess this will fail, if cell values are more than 1 character.` of [TheMaster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165736/readjust-four-column-values-by-ignoring-blank-cells-google-sheets/64167150#comment113481449_64167150), I tested it as follows.

[image]

### Added 2:

For OP's new situation, I added the below modified formula. In this case, the regex is modified.

#### Modified formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:D),"(([\w\s\S]+?,){4})","$1@"),"@")),",")))
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: I guess this will fail, if cell values are more than 1 character.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. I added a test result in my answer. Could you please confirm it? But I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your comment. So can you provide the detail of it? For example, if the values include the special characters, I think that the regex is required to be modified.

Comment: Seems I misunderstood. 

Comment: @Tanaike Good night, I'm sorry about that but could you help me adjust the formula to the values if I have in the spreadsheet? I tried to modify in the places where you indicated but I was not successful. 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DyG5_KyIvK5KeLDxltHARQfi9pa9U4bao2qNl2mTI40/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Brondby IF About your new situation, I added one more modified formula. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @TheMaster Now I thought that `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:D),"(([\w\s\S]+?,){4})","$1@"),"@")),",")))` in the section of "Added 2" might be suitable for more various situations. For example, when `4` of `{4}` is changed, the number of columns can be controlled.

Comment: I think You can also use `"([^,]*,){4}","$0@"`

Comment: @TheMaster Yes. That regex can also be used. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to thank you both for your help and detail in the publications!

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.