# Parse JSON with regexextract

Tags: json, regex, google-sheets

Could you please help me parsing some JSON content in Google Sheet cells?

I can match the first pattern with regex capturing groups, but not the following ones. I didn't succeed to put the /gmi options or to adapt my case from some other code examples, and I'm wasting my time again since 2 days. Thanks a lot.

The json in cell :

```
[
{"idcode":"1AGLG";parent:"1A";level:"Genus";title:"Aglaonema";IsGroup:true};
{"idcode":"1ALDG";parent:"1A";level:"Genus";title:"Alocasia";IsGroup:true};
{"idcode":"1BBSG";parent:"1A";level:"Genus";title:"Ambrosina";IsGroup:true};{"idcode":"1AMUG";parent:"1A";level:"Genus";title:"Amorphophallus";IsGroup:true}
]
```

My formula :

```
REGEXEXTRACT(A1; """idcode"":""([\w]+)""(?:.*?title:"")([\w]+)""")
```

And the sheet file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17YSCK2S8IeqFE_Y_kqWQLVwT9VONXkxvCY3Hlr-8Xpc/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[\[{}\]]",""),"""idcode"":""([\w]+)""(?:.*?title:"")([\w]+)"";IsGroup:true;?","$1,$2,"),"(([\w\s\S]+?,){2})","$1@"),"@")),",")))
```

- In this sample formula, the value of `[{"idcode":"1AGLG";parent:"1A";level:"Genus";title:"Aglaonema";IsGroup:true};{"idcode":"1ALDG";parent:"1A";level:"Genus";title:"Alocasia";IsGroup:true};{"idcode":"1BBSG";parent:"1A";level:"Genus";title:"Ambrosina";IsGroup:true};{"idcode":"1AMUG";parent:"1A";level:"Genus";title:"Amorphophallus";IsGroup:true}]` is put in the cell "A1".
- The flow of this formula is as follows.

  1. Replace `[\[{}\]]` in the original value with `""` using `REGEXREPLACE`.
  2. Replace `""idcode"":""([\w]+)""(?:.*?title:"")([\w]+)"";IsGroup:true;?` in the 1st replaced value with `$1,$2,` using `REGEXREPLACE`.
  3. Split the 2nd replaced value with 2 columns.

     - In this case, I used [the method of this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64165736/7108653).

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- As other method, the following sample formula can be retrieved the same result with above formula. In this formula, `SPLIT` is used 2 times using `@` and `,`.

  ```
    =ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[\[{}\]]",""),"""idcode"":""([\w]+)""(?:.*?title:"")([\w]+)"";IsGroup:true;?","$1,$2@"),"@")),","))
  ```
- If `,` and `@` are included in the values of the original value, please change above formulas.

#### References:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [Readjust four column values by ignoring blank cells (Google Sheets)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64165736/7108653)

Comment: Thank you very much, your second formula works like a charm (I didn't succeed with the first one)

Answer (score 1):

One could also use the following formulas where we use 2 capturing groups with `REGEXREPLACE` in combination with the `JOIN`  function, **or** `REGEXEXTRACT` for more *"flexibility"*.

In both cases an `ArrayFormula` as well as the `SPLIT` function are a must:

#### As a single cell

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN(" / ",REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT($A1,"};{",0), 
                                         ".*(\d\D{2,5})"".*""(\D+)"".*$","$1 - $2")))
```

#### In separate cells in a row

```
={ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT($A1,"};{",0),"(\d\D{2,5})"""));
  ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT($A1,"};{",0),".*""(\D+)"".*$"))}
```

#### In separate cells as a list

```
={ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT($A1,"};{",0),"(\d\D{2,5})"""))),
  ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT($A1,"};{",0),".*""(\D+)"".*$")))}
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
- [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: Thank you very much again marikamitsos, your formula works perfectly and looks elegant. Sorry I can't validate twice the answers

Comment: Tanaike's formula seems less elegant but it matches exactly what I want between the " ". I'l try to make a mix with yours

Comment: *...what I want between the " "*. What is it that you want? I think it does match your example. If you have something else, please let me know.

Comment: With Tanaike's formula I can specify the query with a 'flag name' (for example matching the following word of "parent", or in another json situation with different flags). I hope to be more precised, anyway you both have helped me to solve my problem, please don't blame because me I can't validate 2 solutions.. Thank you so much again

Comment: **After testing[your formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64308306/1527780) with your original example, it gave me [wrong results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgLiv.png)**. Am I missing something? Also. Could you please give an example for your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287886/parse-json-with-regexextract/64289333#comment113715629_64289333)?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutetly right, I have removed  ;"," at the end of the formula. I think it is ok now. I didn't really have time to really improve it for other situations.Thank you very much for your pertinent remark !

Comment: Your welcome. Could you please humor my curiosity and give an example for your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287886/parse-json-with-regexextract/64289333?noredirect=1#comment113715629_64289333) *"specify the query with a 'flag name'"*?. Thanks.

Comment: I have done it, but not finished, please see the sheet

Comment: @Nad Thank you. I'll have a look later again, after you finish.

Comment: No elegant optimisation proposal ? ^^

Comment: I've been quite busy lately. Sorry. Also. Some of your examples have a flag there while others don't. Is there any particular example you want to "fix"? Or is it all of them?

Comment: I would have liked to have a simplest regex formula, regarding my last example, something more intuitive detecting the respective position of each indicated flag with(out) quotation marks, like {""flag1"";"parent";"3rdFlag"}, to retrieve their following string

Answer (score 0):

I have finally mixed both formulas in order to specify the targetted flags and to match more than one word following them :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(join(" ; ";TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1;"[\[{}\]]";"");"""idcode"":""(\d\D{2,5})""(?:.*?title:"")(\D+)"";IsGroup:true;?";"$1
= $2@");"@"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract anything between quotation marks after a given pattern (here the word 'parent') (inspired by [marikamitsos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1527780/marikamitsos))

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN(" ; ";REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT($B20;"};{";0); 
                                         ".*(parent):""((.+?))"".*$";"$1 = $2")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract between-brackets strings following 3 given patterns (that are here 'flag1', 'parent', '3rdFlag')

**json text example :**

[{"flag1":"1AGLG";parent:"1A is 2nd to retrive";level:"Genus";3rdFlag:"Aglaonema is the way i like it"};{"flag1":"1ALDG";parent:"12A is 2nd to retrive";level:"Genus";3rdFlag:"Alocasia"};{"flag1":"1AOWG";parent:"BA is 2nd to retrive";level:"Genus";3rdFlag:"Anchomanes"};{"flag1":"1AUIG";parent:"1A is 2nd to retrive";level:"Genus";3rdFlag:"Anubias"};{"flag1":"1AQOG";parent:"2CA is 2nd to retrive";level:"Genus";3rdFlag:"Ariopsis at the end"}]

**Formula :**

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN(" ; ";REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT($B24;"};{";0); 
                                         ".*(flag1"":""(.+?)"")(.+?)(parent:""(.+?)"")(.+?)(3rdFlag:""(.+?)"").*$";"$2 / $5 / $8")))
```

**Result :**

1AGLG / 1A is 2nd to retrive / Aglaonema is the way i like it ; 1ALDG / 12A is 2nd to retrive / Alocasia ; 1AOWG / BA is 2nd to retrive / Anchomanes ; 1AUIG / 1A is 2nd to retrive / Anubias ; 1AQOG / 2CA is 2nd to retrive / Ariopsis at the end